# generating 52 random cards from a deck of cards without getting duplicates

Tags: python, random

This is what I've come up so far:

```
import time
from random import randint

Suits = [
    ["Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Joker", "Queen", "King"], #hearts
    ["Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Joker", "Queen", "King"], #clubs
    ["Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Joker", "Queen", "King"], #spades
    ["Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Joker", "Queen", "King"]  #diamonds
    ]


for x in range(0,52):
    #selection of random card and suit
    Suit = randint(0,3) 
    Card = randint(0,12)

    # prints what card was received from the deck
    if Suit == 0:
        print("You got a", Suits[0][Card], "of Hearts")
    elif Suit == 1:
        print("You got a", Suits[1][Card], "of Clubs")
    elif Suit == 2:
        print("You got a", Suits[2][Card], "of Spades")
    else:
        print("You got a", Suits[3][Card], "of Diamonds")
```

This allows me to generate a random card from a deck of cards 53 times, but I end up getting duplicates. How would I avoid this?

Comment: the algorithm you are looking for is called a "shuffle"

Comment: Could you generate them in sequence and then shuffle them? Also there are only 52 combinations so there should be at least one duplicate at card 53

Comment: By pigeon hole theorem, there must be atleast one duplicate card

Answer (score 4):

You can do this more simply if you don't really need the 2-dimensional array. If you just have a flat list you can use Python's [random](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/random.html) library to do this easily:

```
import random

cards = [(s, v) for s in ['H', 'S', 'C', 'D'] 
         for v in [str(i) for i in range(2, 11)] + list("JKQA")]

random.shuffle(cards)
```

A list comprehension is used to set `cards` to tuples with the combinations of suits and ranks. Then [`random.shuffle`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/random.html#random.shuffle) is used to randomize the list of cards in place so you can just iterate/pull cards off the end of the list.

Answer (score 1):

```
import random
import itertools as it


deck = list(it.product("♠♣♥♦", [str(x) for x in range(2, 11)] + list("JQKA")))
random.shuffle(deck)

print(len(deck))
print(deck)
# 52
# [('♠', '6'), ('♦', 'J'), ('♣', '4'), ('♣', '7'), ('♠', '8'), ('♦', 'K'), ...]
```

Alternatively, use sets:

```
deck = set(it.product("♠♣♥♦", {str(x) for x in range(2, 11)} | set("JQKA")))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a memoization helper to put the values into a set, then if the value is in the set it will not add it and choose another random card until all 52 cards are in the list of choices.  Thus dealing with any duplicates

```
import random
import itertools as it

deck = list(it.product("♠♣♥♦", [str(x) for x in range(2, 11)] + list("JQKA")))
random.shuffle(deck)

# print(len(deck))
# print(deck)

memo = set()  
def deal(n):

    for i in range(n):
        k = random.choice(deck)
        if k not in memo:
            memo.add(k)
        else:
            deal(1)
    print(len(memo))
    return memo           

print(deal(52))
```

you can do

```
return sorted(memo)
```

This will return a sorted list for easier visual confirmation